# Keep more than two values in a dataframe

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this

```
df <- data.frame(ID = sample(rep(letters, each=3)), value = rnorm(n=26*3))
keep <- c("a", "d", "r", "x")
```

How is it possible to keep both "a" and "d"

example using something like this: `df[df$ID == "a"|"d", ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%in%`

```r
df[df$ID %in% c("a","d"), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use base R function `which()`. `which()` returns indexes where given condition is met.

```
df[which(df$ID == "a" | df$ID == "d"),]
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `%chin%`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ID %chin% c('a', 'd')]
```